# Logistic regression coefficients in weka LMT tree

Tags: weka, decision-tree, logistic-regression

How can I obtain the coefficients of the regression function in the LMT leave nodes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should come up by default.

The screenshot below contains the coefficients that are generated using LMT:

[image: LMT Coefficients for Leaves]

This result was achieved without changes to LMT Default Parameters on a Randomly generated dataset and using Weka 3.7.11.

From Java, the [LMT.ToString()](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/LMT.html#toString%28%29) method should give you the leaves of the tree.

Comment: thanks @MatthewSpencer. I am not working with Weka GUI, but using the java code directly. I can visualize the tree through the graph() command, but it only details the inner nodes. For the leaves I see the number of the LM, but I don't see the coefficients.

Comment: I believe that the [LMT.ToString()](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/LMT.html#toString%28%29) method should give you the leaves.